# Как зафиксировать изображение для разных разрешений?

Tags: unity3d

Какие существуют способы сохранения эталонного изображения при запуске на разных форматах разрешения?
Под "изображением" я подразумеваю в целом картину, наблюдаемую на экране, а не конкретно `Image` - т.е. и интерфейс, и объекты на сцене. Желаемый результат представляю примерно так:

[image: 16:9 - эталон, в остальных форматах появляются рамки]

Интерфейс **не адаптируется** под разрешения, объекты на сцене - тоже. Картинка на любых разрешениях должна оставаться неизменной (конечно же, не считая необходимых искажений, типа зума камеры и рамок по сторонам).

В качестве ответа хочется увидеть небольшой список вариантов "*фиксации*", желательно с описанием плюсов-минусов каждого варианта.

Comment: А чем anchors не подошли? Там довольно гибкая настройка.

Comment: @trollingchar с помощью якорей, я могу зафиксировать интерфейс - это я знаю. А что делать с отображением объектов на сцене в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Нормальный способ

Назвал его так, потому что не вижу недостатков. Он простой и правильно работает. Но я не знаю, как приспособить его для 3D мира.

Сначала скажу, что нам понадобится канва. Канва, когда ее создаешь, имеет компонент **Canvas Scaler**. Его ставим на **Expand** и указываем разрешение канвы. В моем примере это 1000 x 600. Там мы создадим 4 черных изображения (это будут наши черные полоски по краям, хотя мы можем сделать их и не черными, а даже с текстурой) и поставим такие свойства:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результаты на разных разрешениях экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерфейс мы будем под пустым объектом в канве, настроенным на выравнивание по центру и размер 1000 x 600. Важно: он должен идти *до* черных полосок, иначе когда часть интерфейса за них улезет, то ее будет видно.

Осталось настроить камеру. У меня в проекте это делает скрипт с такой строчкой в апдейте:

```
camera.orthographicSize = Screen.height * zoom;
```

Можете теперь настроить `zoom` как вы обычно настраиваете у камеры `orthographicSize`. Однако, если проект в 3д, предположительно, надо менять **Field of view**, но точной формулы сказать не могу.

## Использование RenderTexture

На мой взгляд, кривой способ, однако упоминаю его как еще один возможный.

Делаем канву и черные полоски по аналогии. Создаем **RenderTexture**, ставим ей нужное нам разрешение. Камер у нас будет две, одна отрисовывает объекты сцены на текстуру, другая показывает канву с черными полосками и нашей текстурой. Текстуру отображаем при помощи **RawImage**, якоря по центру, размеры 1000 x 600. У той камеры, которая снимает мир, убираем UI из маски, второй камере наоборот ставим только UI. И добавляем интерфейс в дочерние объекты этой текстуры.

Недостатки этого метода в том, что качество картинки может потеряться, если разрешение поставить слишком большое - будут видны большие размытые пиксели, а у интерфейса будет все нормально с этим. Частично это решается установкой в 2 раза большего разрешения - 2000 x 1200. И еще недостаток это то что надо возиться с камерами и слоями.

Comment: Не совсем понял, зачем в `camera.orthographicSize = Screen.height * zoom` используется высота экрана, ведь в одном и том же формате могут быть совершенно разные высоты экрана (1600х900, 1920х1080 и т.д.). Но вектор мысли понятен, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @MikhailDeyman орфографическая камера подстраивается почему-то только по высоте. Как делает камера с перспективой, пока не знаю. Возможно, надо менять FOV, а может viewport. Если когда-нибудь буду этим заниматься, дополню ответ.